# Least value of $(α-β)$ if area is minimum.

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

> The area of parallelogram formed by the lines $$x \cos \alpha +y\sin\alpha = p,$$ $$x \cos\alpha +y\sin\alpha = q,$$ $$x\cos\beta + y\sin\beta = r$$ and $$x\cos\beta + y\sin\beta = s$$ for given values of $p,q,r$ and $s$ is least , if $(α-β) =?$

Find four points of intersection and then minimizing the area does not seem a good approach. Is there any smarter way to do it?

Comment: Can minimum area be $0$?

Comment: @Aniket No and I don't think its possible here .

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines are two parallel lines which make angle $\pi/2+\alpha$ with the positive X-axis and are at distances $|p-q|$ from each other.

The other two lines are two parallel lines which make angle $\pi/2+\beta$ with the positive X-axis and are at distance $|r-s|$.

The angle between the two pairs will obviously be $\alpha-\beta$

So if you draw a figure it will be clear that the area $$A=|p-q||r-s||\csc(\alpha-\beta)|$$

So $|\alpha-\beta|$ should be $\pi/2$